# How to jailbreak on an iOS 10.2 on an iPhone 5s

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, ios, hacking

I'm aware of jailbreaking on iPhone 6 with version 10.2, but what about iPhone 5s? (I want to show off my phone with cool features), one of thing I want to do is replacing default Helvetica with San Francisco, unless Helvetica was intended by the website or app.

Answer (score 1):

As per my little knowledge regarding iOS, I found Yalu jailbreak is updated and release to jailbreak iPhone 5S.

> Step 1: First up, connect your compatible iPhone or iPad device to a
>   Windows or Mac computer using a Lightning/USB cable.
>
> Step 2: As a precaution, make a complete backup of the data on the
>   device using iTunes so that you can return to it in case anything goes
>   wrong with the jailbreak process you are about to perform.
>
> Step 3: Launch Cydia Impactor on your computer.
>
> Step 4: Drag and drop the yalu102 IPA file you downloaded earlier on
>   Cydia Impactor.
>
> Step 6: Wait for Cydia Impactor to install the yalu102 jailbreak app
>   onto your iPhone or iPad.
>
> Step 7: Once installed, disconnect your device from computer and head
>   to Settings >  General > Profile(s) & Device Management or General >
>   Device Management and hit Trust and then Trust again on the
>   certificate you used to install this jailbreak app.

For detailed tutorial, please check [Redmond Pie](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-jailbreak-ios-10.2-with-yalu102-tutorial/) or [Team Cydia](http://teamcydia.com/how-to-jailbreak-iphone-7-7-plus-6-plus-6s-and-ipad-on-ios-10-2-using-yalu-jailbreak/).

Comment: hi guys, how do you install cydia onto the computer? Do you do it just like other software? And is it actually possible to replace default Helvetica font on websites and apps, to San Francisco? The only exception to keep the Helvetica font is if the designers **specifically** specify it. For example, the Wikipedia page can have the change, because, it just specifies any sans-serif font.

Comment: @awesomekimbos Your comment is extremely unclear. If you have a clarifying/followup question about M Ibrahim's answer, please restate it; otherwise, consider asking a new question using the link at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As of today you can't jailbreak an iPhone 5s running iOS 10.2.

The JB depends on a specific CPU exploit which is not available with the 5s' CPU.